# Perl output successive string from array

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach

I have an array I can print out as "abcd" however I am trying to print it as "a>ab>abc>abcd".  I can't figure out the nested loop I need within the foreach loop I have. What loop do I need within it to print it this way?

```
my $str = "a>b>c>d";
my @words = split />/, $str;

foreach my $i (0 .. $#words) {
print $words[$i], "\n";
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why use `split` or arrays? `substr` in a loop is your friend.

Comment: Or try with an accumulating variable `my $a ='' ;` which is 1) augmented (concatenated) by `$words[$i]` and then 2) printed in each loop iteration

Comment: What is really your input? A string or an array? Here you have both `$str` and `@words`, and it's unclear if `@words` comes from your attempt at solving your problem, or it's actually your input.

Comment: my input will be reading lines from a CSV file and which will contain strings in the format of "a>b>d>e".  I am trying to output a value of "a>ab>abc>abcd".

Answer (score 4):

You had the right idea, but instead of printing the word at position i, you want to print all the words between positions 0 and i (inclusive). Also, your input can contain multiple strings, so loop over them.

```
use warnings;

while (my $str = <>) {              # read lines from stdin or named files
  chomp($str);                      # remove any trailing line separator

  my @words = split />/, $str;      # break string into array of words
  foreach my $i (0 .. $#words) {
    print join '', @words[0 .. $i]; # build the term from the first n words
    print '>' if $i < $#words;      # print separator between terms (but not at end)
  }

  print "\n";
}
```

There are many other ways to write it, but hopefully this way helps you understand what's happening and why. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

one liner:

```
perl -e '@a=qw(a b c d); for(@a) {$s.=($h.=$_).">"} $s=substr($s,0,-1);print $s'
```

Comment: Thank you, This appends a ">" to the end, is there anyway to remove that?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with, It's the only way I could understand and get the output I was looking for.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "a>b>c>d>e>f>g";
my @words = split />/, $str;

my $j = $#words;
my $i = 0;
my @newtax; 
while($i <= $#words){
        foreach my $i (0 .. $#words - $j){
            push (@new, $words[$i]);
    }

    if($i < $#words){
        push(@new, ">");
    }
    $j--;
    $i++;
}

print @new;
```

This output "a>ab>abc>abcd>abcde>abcdef>abcdefg"

Comment: If this is clearest for you then I suggest to work to understand the solution by @mwp, as most similar but far simpler.  (Note, all should be either `@new` or `@newtax`)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "a>b>c>d>e>f>g";
my @words = split />/, $str;

$" = '';
my @new_words;

push @new_words, "@words[0 .. $_]" for 0 .. $#words;

print join '>', @new_words;
```

A few things to explain.

Perl will expand array variables in a double-quoted string. So something like this:

```
@array = ('x', 'y', 'z');
print "@array";
```

will print `x y z`. Notice there are spaces between the elements. The string that is inserted between the elements is controlled by the `$"` variable. So by setting  that variable to an empty string we can remove the spaces, so:

```
$" = '';
@array = ('x', 'y', 'z');
print "@array";
```

will print `xyz`.

The most complex line is:

```
push @new_words, "@words[0 .. $_]" for 0 .. $#words;
```

That's just a compact way to write:

```
for (0 .. $#words) {
  my $new_word = "@words[0 .. $_]";
  push @new_words, $new_word;
}
```

We iterate across the integers from zero to the last index in `@words`. Each time around the loop, we use an array slice to get a list of elements from the array, convert that to a string (by putting it in double-quotes) and then push that string onto `@new_words`.